# How to transition: leaving an EdD before completing to pursue a masters in another area

Tags: changing-fields, quitting

I finished half of my comps for an EdD program that I really have no interest in finishing. I would actually like to pursue a second masters in a different area, but I have no idea how to do so, and it's a sticky situation to ask these questions of the university advisor. Basically, I want to move in a different direction with my career, and a second masters will bolster that rather than completing the EdD track I'm currently on. I basically have 12 more comps before I can even write dissertation anyway. Rather than pay tuition another semester for a degree I will not finish, I'm interested in how to transition and if I will run into any issues because I leave this current program with admission to another.

Comment: What is an EdP?

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "how to transition" - what kind of information are you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Finish it off.  Do it as fast and easy as possible.  The doctorate is more impressive than a second masters.  You are half way through.

Note I am extremely skeptical of academia and grad degrees and often tell people to do an MBA instead or just work.  But once you are in it, finish, finish, finish.

And remember, it is pass fail.  Just get through it with the minimum.  ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

If you are really interested in a different career, one that an EdD won't help you with, just make a clean break. However, make sure that you investigate the consequences thoroughly so that you don't wind up in a couple of years in a similar situation.

People change their minds all the time. As they learn more about a career they may discover that there as aspects of it that no longer interest them. There is nothing wrong, or even unusual, about that. Take care of yourself first.

You may need to change universities to do this, but I see no particular reason you shouldn't discuss it with a trusted professor. Your advisor is supposed to provide you with *good* advice, of course.